# Parsing Time field from Postgres db in rails 6 to retrieve hour and minute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a model Open times for shops.  The open times tables comprises a field as below.  I would like to query the opening and closing times like:  08:00 - 17:00

```
t.time "closes"
```

the view helpers is the following:  <%= display_day(0) %>. where 0 is sunday

I get to the following array with pluck.

```
=> [Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 UTC +00:00]
```

I would like to ignore the date component and only show Hours and Minutes.

Thanks to tadman and Caleb, we could get to the following:

```rb
def display_day(value)
  is_open = @company.opentimes.where(day: value, openpublic: true)
  if is_open.pluck(:openpublic) == false
    'closed'
  else
    start = is_open.pluck(:opens)
    close = is_open.pluck(:closes)
    if start.nil?
      'no data'
    else
      DateTime.parse(start[0].to_s).strftime('%H.%M')
      DateTime.parse(close[0].to_s).strftime('%H.%M')
    end
  end
end
```

I will clean the code and post it there. in the meantime, if you have any suggestions, feel free to suggest.

Comment: Tip: Within Rails you don't want `puts`, you want to return that string instead.

Comment: Note you can get both values in one query: `pluck(:opens, :closes)`.

Comment: You can format a [DateTime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) however you want, normally using `to_s` with a format specifier or `strftime` with a custom format string.

Comment: Thanks for the hints especially on the pluck single query.  I have tried to formate the Time field but could not get anywhere.

What can I try ?

Comment: I don't get why you think you want to use pluck in the first place as it gives you strings instead of time objects. Just iterate through the records and use [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: That code is also pretty much completely broken. pluck returns an array so `@company.opentimes.where(day: value).pluck(:openpublic) == true` is always false.

Comment: comments of invaluable usefulness to me.

Comment: If  your query includes `openpublic: true` then won't your check for `is_open.pluck(:openpublic) == false` *always* fail, because `openpublic` should never be false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use both the DateTime `parse` and [`strftime`](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) methods to format the time however you want.

Based on the plucking you're doing:

```rb
start = @company.opentimes.where(day: value).pluck(:opens)
=> [Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 UTC +00:00]

DateTime.parse(start[0].to_s).strftime('%H:%M')
=> "08:00"
```

You could create a little formatting helper like:

```rb
def format_time(time)
  DateTime.parse(time.to_s).strftime('%H.%M')
end
```

And then use this to return the final string like: `08.00 - 17.00`:

```rb
def hours_open(day)
  opentime = @company.opentimes.where(day: day, openpublic: true).first

  if opentime.opens && opentime.closes
    "#{format_time opentime.opens} - #{format_time opentime.closes}"
  elsif !opentime
    'closed'
  else
    'no data'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.

I could with the to_s conversion as follows:

'DateTime.parse(start[0].to_s).strftime('%H.%M')'

Comment: I updated my answer and made some tweaks to your final solution! Let me know if this is useful!

Comment: all good but I have adjusted with
    `if opentime.try(:opens) && opentime.try(:closes)`
or
    `if opentime&.opens && opentime&.closes`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the strftime method?

```
Time.now.strftime('%T')    # this will output something like "15:26:54"
Time.now.strftime('%H:%M') # this will output something like "15:26"
```

Comment: Marcelo,  maybe I am massively missing something but the time is store in a pg table in rails.  So I need to retrieve the data which is stored as time (Time filed not DateTime).   when I do:

    `@model.@nested_model.c.opentimes.where(day:1, openpublic: true).pluck(:opens)`

i retrieve that data array:
    `[Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 UTC +00:00]`

Comment: What about doing the following?
@model.@nested_model.c.opentimes.where(day:1, openpublic: true).pluck(:opens).map { |d| d.strftime('%H:%M') }